# cant load data from picker on first page load but when visiting page second time picker loads as expected

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml

I have xamarin page that shows list of products and a picker which represents type of product.
My problem is that when i start application and try to access page for the first time,
in debugging mode i can see that list i am using as ItemsSource has value,
But when page is loaded picker is greyed out and doesnt have any data.
When I leave page with picker and open it up second time, picker is loaded with data!
 
Here is my code!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         
         xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:eProdaja.Mobile.Converters"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="Restoran.Mobile.Views.ProizvodiPage">

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Converters:ImageConverter x:Key="imgConv"></Converters:ImageConverter>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding TipProizvodaList}"  ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Naziv}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTipProizvoda}"></Picker>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ProizvodiList}" ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout  Padding="10" Margin="5" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                            <Image Source="{Binding Slika, Converter={StaticResource imgConv}}" ></Image>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Naziv}" 
                            d:Text="{Binding .}"
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                            FontSize="16" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                            <Button  HorizontalOptions="Center" BorderColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="OrangeRed" Text="Dodaj u košaricu"></Button>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>



        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code inside of xaml.cs

```
private ProizvodiViewModel model = null;
        public ProizvodiPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = model = new ProizvodiViewModel();
        }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await model.Init();
    }
```

Code inside of viewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<TipProizvoda> TipProizvodaList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TipProizvoda>();

 public async Task Init()
    {

         if (TipProizvodaList.Count == 0)
        {
            var TPList = await _tipProizvoda.Get<List<TipProizvoda>>(null);
            TipProizvodaList.Clear();
            TipProizvoda empty = new TipProizvoda { TipProizvodaID = 0, Naziv = "" };
            TipProizvodaList.Add(empty);

            foreach (var tipProizvoda in TPList)
            {
                TipProizvodaList.Add(tipProizvoda);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: first, if the problem is with your Picker, why did you not post that code?  Second, you are defining the BindingContext in the XAML **and** the code behind.  Pick one or the other, not both

Comment: As @Jason said, you have set the page BindingContext  twice. And  you have not posted the xaml code with picker. we can't use above code the make a repro sample.

Comment: @Jason Hi! thanks for trying to help, i added full xaml page code and removed definition of binding context in XAML

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Hi! thanks for trying to help, i added full xaml page code and removed definition of binding context in XAML

Comment: are you ever reinitializing `TipProizvodaList` when you add data to it, or are you always using the `Add()` method?

Comment: @Jason updated the code with function

Answer (score 0):

Over the years, I've had various problems attempting to do ANYTHING in `OnAppearing` that affects what is seen on screen.

There must be something Xamarin does AFTER OnAppearing, that gets the page into a valid state to receive binding changes.

One way around this limitation is to **delay** the work that you want done, so that `OnAppearing` returns **before** your work sets the bindings.

The "downside" of this, is that the page will appear (at first) **without** your work. See the two references to "activityIndicator" - those are where you control what you want user to see before your work is ready.

The "upside" of this, is that it ensures Xamarin "sees" your binding changes. (It also provides a place to do slow background work, if that is needed.)

Try this:

```
public partial class MyPage : ...
{
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        This returns immediately, allowing OnAppearing to return.
        DelayWork(100, BackgroundWork, UIWork);
    }
    
    // Custom class, used to pass results from background work to UI work.
    class BackgroundResult {
        ...
    }
    
    private void DelayWork(int milliseconds, Func<BackgroundResult> backgroundWork, Action uiWork)
    {
        //OPTIONAL activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;

        Task.Run( () => {
            // The delay ensures Xamarin page preparation has a little time, before your work begins.
            // Without this delay, under some circumstances, the page might not show up as quickly.
            // You might not need this.
            Task.Delay(milliseconds);
            
            // Slow work -- do nothing that affects UI.
            BackgroundResult backgroundResult = BackgroundWork();
            
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
                await uiWork(backgroundResult);
            });
        });
    }

    private BackgroundResult BackgroundWork()
    {
        // Slow work -- do nothing that affects UI.
        ...
        
        // fill this with whatever info you need to pass to UIWork.
        var backgroundResult = new BackgroundResult();
        // ...
        return backgroundResult;
    }

    private async void UIWork(BackgroundResult backgroundResult)
    {
        // Work that affects UI, possibly via Bindings.
        await model.Init();

        //OPTIONAL activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
    }
}
```

In your situation, you might not need BackgroundWork nor BackgroundResult. Shown for completeness.