# Xamarin - load data on thread other than main

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When a page is loaded I run some code that loads items from SQLite DB. Thus (I believe so) the page loading animation is not smooth. So I decided to load the data in advance in `App.OnStart`.

```
Task.Run(itemsStore.LoadItemsAsync);
```

Then problem is that it is always run in the main thread. I tried to do a trick like this inside `LoadItemsAsync`:

```
        while (MainThread.IsMainThread)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"ItemsStore.DoLoadItemsAsync: (2) Is main thread: {MainThread.IsMainThread}");
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
```

but then the application hangs.

So my question is: How to load data really in the background and why the trick above does not work? I tried to use `Task.Yield` as well.

**Updated**

I've changed app's `OnStart` method from:

```
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        var itemStore = DependencyService.Get<IItemStore>();
        itemsStore.Init(); // !!! HERE THE CHANGE !!!
        Task.Run(itemsStore.LoadItemsAsync);
    }
```

to

```
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        var itemStore = DependencyService.Get<IItemStore>();
        Task.Run(() => itemsStore.Init());  // !!! HERE THE CHANGE !!!
        Task.Run(itemsStore.LoadItemsAsync);
    }
```

And now it doesn't run solely on the main thread. Could anybody explain it to me?

Comment: You need to add more code to your question, specifically the LoadItemsAsync body.
One possible approach may be to call `itemsStore.LoadItemsAsync()` without an `await` in front of it

Comment: 1) Whatever you put inside `Task.Run` is ready to run on a background thread. UNLESS you ".Wait" or something. So the problem must be something else in LoadItemsAsync. Or something you don't show just before or after the `Task.Run` line.  Show more code in question. 2) That trick does nothing useful. Code never automagically changes from MainThread to a different thread.

Comment: Re how to do this correctly, I show two examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68775760/199364) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69693662/199364). In first example, I use  `Task.Delay` inside `Run`, to make sure XForms loads the empty page without delay. (I pause the background work for a short while.))

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for comments. I'll definitely try out the trick with delay. But in the meantime I've update my question. You where right that "the problem must be something else". Maybe you can answer my last question?

Comment: Look at my code in my first link. See how "BackgroundWork" does everything that *needs* to run in the background. Then when it is done, it calls `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`. Inside that, you put code that needs to be on main thread. The `OnStart` code you posted has a flaw. The whole point of `Task.Run` is to start something running in the background. That means the first `Task.Run` line **may not have finished running when the second Task.Run line starts**. It might be okay, but it might not. Instead, make **one** Task.Run, and put everything inside it. As shown in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small example for your reference.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <CollectionView x:Name="mytest">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding .}"></Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the cs code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection<string> ts = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mytest.ItemsSource = ts;
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var result = Task.Run(() => myTest());
    }

    private void myTest()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);//Time spent in simulated query
        ts.Add("aaa");
        ts.Add("bbb");
        ts.Add("ccc");
    }
}
```

But according to your statement, I am not sure how much data your database has, for quick queries. Using **index** in the database is the best way to improve query efficiency.